# Help understanding CLM equation "If x∼N(μ,σ) then x¯∼N(μ,σn‾√)"

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Stats n00b. What does N(μ, σ) mean?

I'm trying to piece it all together, but can't fill in all the gaps (search engines don't recognise it and I can't seem to find anywhere that uses this same formula for CLM.

It's in the context of If x∼N(μ,σ) then x¯∼N(μ,σn‾√)

So, something like, for a given value x, x is distributed as the total number of items in the population, something about the mean and standard deviation, but I don't understand the brackets and comma (and no idea if I'm on the mark at all).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It’s a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have seen something like "if $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are identically and independently distributed, then their sample average $\overline X_n\sim N(\mu,(\sigma /\sqrt n)^2)$."  Statements like    this are often found in introductory stats courses and textbooks and Wikipedia articles (such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Distribution_of_the_sample_mean))  and take unpacking to make sense.  Wikipedia articles on "Normal distribution" and "Sample mean" might help you follow the unpacking and to hone your question.

Comment: Thanks but it's still above my head. What is the meaning of (,2)? I'm still lost at that level and struggling to find an answer because I don't know how to search for that (unfortunately a bit of a gap between what I'm studying and my basic understanding of such functions that I'm trying to bridge).

Comment: $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ means that $X$ follows a normal distribution with means $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

Comment: Ahhh, OK, that makes sense now! Matches the text. I just didn't realise the link.

Comment: Thank you so much. I look at so much of what I've been reading and it joined the dots